Using Data out instead of B out in WS2813-V3 wiring
In a string of WS2813C-V3 (this is a newer version of WS2813C but for pin1, has a backup out pin instead of a NC pin), is there a reason why not to use data out instead of backup out as the input to the backup pin in the following led?
The datasheet recommends direct BO-BIN connection, however, the quality of said datasheet is very poor.

How I understand the backup line functionality in WS2813 family that the bin input discards first 24 bits of signal, and then compares to din input signal, and if different, follows bin signal (with a 24 bit shift).
But I can't understand why this newer design would need an independent bout line if this is the case. I.e. what would be the issue with the following, i.e using the previous data out (of N LEDs) as the Bin of N+2 LEDs.  Previous other WS2813C LEDs used this wiring, but I'm not sure if there's some kind of gotcha I'm missing here.


As you say, the datasheet is unclear... it could simply be to ease routing - Note that "in" are on the left of the package, and "out" are on the right - perhaps DI and BO are internally connected to give the equivelant wiring you've shown. I suspect the best way to answer this, is to get your hands on a few... I'd start by testing for continuity between DI and BO.

Thanks @Attie - I have tried testing but no continuity between DI/BO.  On the scope, Bout does seem identical to Din of the same LED wrt timing/level though my scope is fairly low bandwidth.  Is there anything else you'd suggest trying?

BI and BO help to cope with the failure of an individual chip in a long string by providing a backup data stream around the fault. But it's going to be a pretty specific failure that knocks out the DI/DO part of the chip but not the BI/BO part.
